# Python library for genetic algorithm based curve fitting?

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, genetic-algorithm

I'm planning to carry out a curve fitting task using genetic algorithms. For this purpose, I'm looking for an out of the box tool in python. Can you recommend such libraries? So far, I've come across [scipy's optimize.differential_evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html). It looks promising, but before I dive into its specifics, I'd like to get a good sense of what other methods are out there, if any.

Thanks